# Can't figure out how conditional types work

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've got such a piece of code:

```
const f = <T extends string | number>(b: T): T extends string ? number : string => typeof b === "string" ? 2 : "a";
```

and can't figure out why it doesn't work.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=116&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAFRgUwB5U2AEwhmgCcBLMAcxgB8YwBXAWwCNNSA+AClYC4YaAJQCMOPIWJlKNAPwMW7UjAHTqSTjCgBPAA6YQCVkkTIARGqpmY8gEwqYZgIZmA3EA

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand conditional types

Comment: I understand that but what is its intended output when `T` is a `string` or a `number`?

Comment: It's in the code: if `T` is a `string` a want to return `2` and when it's a `number` I want to return `"a"`

Comment: Your code is a bit convoluted - if you move your type definitions to separate `type X = ` statements and use the long-form `function f<T...` syntax then it makes it easier to follow.

Comment: You can't do this, `T` is not "resolved" in function's body. You can use overloads to achieve the same: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAIwFyIM5QE4xgDmAlFmCALZoCmeAUKJLAsuuVbXmTvoUY3DR4SVJl4FiiAD6IK1Oj1ySiMuZzqIA3vUR7EeGlBB4kUAJ4AHGnGCI0iALzPEAImX9XiAPyIATIhYrgCGrgDc9AC+QA

Comment: @AlekseyL. you're a life-saver